# How to convert Nullable<T>[] to T[]

Tags: c#

I have code like this to convert nullable arrays to ordinary arrays

```
        object myCoolConvertion(object value)
        { 
          if (value is int?[])
              return Array.ConvertAll((int? [])value, x => x ?? default(int));
          if (value is double?[])
              return Array.ConvertAll((double?[])value, x => x ?? default(double));
          if (value is float?[])
              return Array.ConvertAll((float?[])value, x => x ?? default(float));
          return value;
        }
```

Is it possible to write universal code for any types like

```
 if (value is T?[])
     return Array.ConvertAll((T? [])value, x => x ?? default(int));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a generic method, e.g.:

```cs
T[] Convert<T>(T?[] array) where T : struct
{
    return Array.ConvertAll(array, t => t ?? default(T));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but variable value in my example has already boxed, so i can't pass it to this generic function..

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note for Iridium's answer:
The `Nullable<T>` has a method called [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=net-6.0%60), which can make your code a bit more concise:

```
T[] Convert<T>(T?[] array) where T : struct
   => Array.ConvertAll(array, t => t.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Comment: `t.GetValueOrDefault()` is more characters than `t ?? default(T)`, so it's actually *less* concise. If you really want concise (and are using a sufficiently recent version of C#), you can use `t ?? default`

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather filter the `null` object's out. Because default structs are not useful and can not be distinguished between a real objects.

I use the [IEnumerable.OfType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-6.0) for this.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static T[] ConvertWithout<T>(T?[] array) where T : struct =>
         array.OfType<T>().ToArray();
    
    public struct TestStruct
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var testArray = new TestStruct?[] 
        {
            new TestStruct { Name = "Peter"}, 
            null, 
            new TestStruct{Name="John"}
        };
        
        var result = ConvertWithout(testArray);
        
        foreach(var person in result)
            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
    }
}
```

results:

```
Peter
John
```